# Getting error (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.Request$Builder.tag) while posting event to microsoft graph

Tags: java, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to hit the microsoft graph api for get and post methods.
Java code:

```
IGraphServiceClient graphClient = 
             GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .buildClient();
 graphClient.me().calendar().events().buildRequest().post(event);
 User user = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
```

On hitting the api I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.Request$Builder.tag(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lokhttp3/Request$Builder;
> at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.getHttpRequest(CoreHttpProvider.java:257)
> at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:397)
> at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:220)
> at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:200)
> at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseRequest.send(BaseRequest.java:345)
> at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.EventRequest.post(EventRequest.java:135)
> at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.EventCollectionRequest.post(EventCollectionRequest.java:75)

Maven versions for graph and graph-auth api's are:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph-auth -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph-auth</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please help me resolve this issue?

This is the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider("{client_id}",
            Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"),
            "{username}", "{password}", NationalCloud.Global,
            "{tenant_id}", "{client_secret}");

    IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .buildClient();

    Event event = new Event();
    event.subject = "Let's go for lunch";
    ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
    body.contentType = BodyType.HTML;
    body.content = "Does mid month work for you?";
    event.body = body;
    DateTimeTimeZone start = new DateTimeTimeZone();
    start.dateTime = "2021-01-15T12:00:00";
    start.timeZone = "Pacific Standard Time";
    event.start = start;
    DateTimeTimeZone end = new DateTimeTimeZone();
    end.dateTime = "2021-01-15T14:00:00";
    end.timeZone = "Pacific Standard Time";
    event.end = end;
    Location location = new Location();
    location.displayName = "";
    event.location = location;
    LinkedList<Attendee> attendeesList = new LinkedList<Attendee>();
    Attendee attendees = new Attendee();

    EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress();
    emailAddress.address = "abc@gmail.com";
    emailAddress.name = "Abcd";
    attendees.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    attendees.type = AttendeeType.REQUIRED;
    attendeesList.add(attendees);

    event.attendees = attendeesList;
    
    graphClient.me().calendar().events().buildRequest().post(event);

    log.info("created the event");

}
```

Comment: Please share how your `main()` method is like. Is the signature correct? Like `public static void main(String [] args)`.

Comment: Modified the question to add main method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing the exception (NoSuchMethodError), you found the class, so you had a okhttp in your classpath. My guess is that an older version of okhttp was used (maybe because of other dependencies) and you got a dependency conflict.

java.lang.NoSucMethodError comes when Java code tries to call a method which doesn't exist in a class, this could be either static or non static method.

Add this dependency and try again.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.9</version>
</dependency>
```

If your application has dependency conflicts, then add this in your
pom.xml to resolve them:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>3.14.9</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Already tried it. Not working.
I am not directly using okhttp3.
I am calling microsoft graph api and at some point that api is using okhttp3.

Comment: yes correct! Could you please check the dependency tree and find the version of okhttp?.

Comment: This is theversion I found using the dependency tree:

com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.9.0:compile

Comment: I am using Java 8

Comment: adding `okhttp` with latest version worked